# how add vuetify in single-spa vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, single-spa

vue 2.6.14
vuetify 2.6.9

How do I plug vuetify into a vue application?
I trying import my project in another project how microfrontend application, but something not working

how i went this step-by-step:

1. create-single-spa root config
2. created application vue in project
3. run vue add vuetify in vue app directory
4. import vuetify in main.js in vue app
5. profit?... no

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@site/site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "serve:standalone": "vue-cli-service serve --mode standalone"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "single-spa-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.9",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-social-sharing": "^3.0.9",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "sass": "~1.54.9",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-single-spa": "~3.3.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

site/main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import singleSpaVue from "single-spa-vue";

import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import VueSocialSharing from "vue-social-sharing";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = process.env.VUE_APP_IS_DEV === "true";

Vue.use(VueSocialSharing);

const vueLifecycles = singleSpaVue({
  Vue,
  appOptions: {
    render(h) {
      return h(App);
    },
    vuetify,
    router,
    store,
  },
});

export const bootstrap = vueLifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = vueLifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = vueLifecycles.unmount;
```

[errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxAY5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to import it from plugins, but you probably didn't create file in plugins

```
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
```

Create a plugin file for Vuetify, src/plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

Use `opts` object to customize [themes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing) if you want

Comment: No, I created plugin file
`import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework";
import "material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: "md",
  },
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        mainColor: "#008ece",
      },
    },
  },
});`

Comment: Sorry, you right!
I wrong import 
 -- error
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework";
--correct
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it

```
Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

with vuetify like you did with VueSocialSharing?

[Vuetify Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install)

Comment: It is not. Since he is importing ```from "./plugins/vuetify"```

Comment: i did it in plugins/vuetify.js
But i tried did it in main.js, it`s not working